# Facebook login windw.fb or window.gapi undefined after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-login, google-signin

I have implemented react-facebook login and react-googel loing using npm packages

react-facebook-login

react-google-login

when I am doing console

```
window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().tokenId

window.FB.getAccessToken()
```

everything is working fine... but if I do refresh the page

window.gapi and window.FB both get undefind..

I believe we might need to reinitialize but don't know how becuause I have not directly use sdk, rather implemented the npm  packages..

Any help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Google sign-in. There are several ways to solve but I chose the simplest one, I initialize the API on every refreshing.